# Joomla after login redirect issue when multilanguage mode is on

Tags: joomla3.0

Found a bug in Joomla 3.3 with redirect after login. If you use multilanguage mode so only redirect works for default language.
So to fix it see the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create user-plugin or to paste the following code to some existent one.

```
public function onUserLogin( $user, $options = array() ) {
   $app = JFactory::getApplication();
   $app->setUserState('users.login.form.return', $options['return']);
}
```

Sure, before this you need to specify desired redirect url when create Login menu item.